# The R equivalent of the Python plotly.tools.FigureFactory.create_scatterplotmatrix?

Tags: python, r, plotly

I'm trying to recreate in R the scatterplotmatrix from the Python plotly tutorial:

http://moderndata.plot.ly/using-plotly-in-jupyter-notebooks-on-microsoft-azure/

I have the dataframe in R, but what is the equivalent plotly code in R to recreate the below Python call?

```
fig = FigureFactory.create_scatterplotmatrix(
    df, diag='histogram', index='manufacturer',
    height=800, width=800,
    title='Motor Trend Car Road Tests Scatterplot Matrix'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ggairs()` function in the GGally package makes it easy to create generalized pairs plots (e.g. scatterplot matrix) via ggplot2, and `ggplotly()` knows how to translate them to plotly.

```
library(GGally)
library(plotly)
ggplotly(ggpairs(iris))
```

Comment: It seems there's no direct equivalent but you can build the same with ggally/ggplotly